# firebase otp verification in React js ( opt coming, after click on verification showing error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

> Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-phone-number).
> FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-phone-number).
> at createErrorInternal (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:12824:37)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-input-2'
import 'react-phone-input-2/lib/style.css'
import { RecaptchaVerifier, signInWithPhoneNumber } from 'firebase/auth'
import { auth } from '../firebase/setup'

function PhoneSining() {
const [phone, setPhone] = useState("")
const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
const [otp, setOtp] = useState("")

const sendOtp = async () => {
try {
const recaptcha = new RecaptchaVerifier(auth, "recaptcha", {})
const confirmation = signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phone, recaptcha)
console.log(confirmation)
setUser(confirmation)
catch (err) {
console.error(err)
         }
     }
const verifyOtp = async () => {
try {
const data = await user.confirm(otp)
console.log(data)
catch (err) {
console.error(err)
await user.confirm(otp)
        }
    }
return (
        <div>
            <PhoneInput
            country={'in'}
            value={phone}
            onChange={(phone) => setPhone("+" + phone)}
            />
            <button onClick={sendOtp}>Send otp</button>
            <div id="recaptcha"></div>
            <div>
                <input type='number' name="number" lavel="enter otp number"
                 onChange={(e) => setOtp(e.target.value)} />
                <button onClick={verifyOtp}>Verify</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default PhoneSining;
```

Comment: Can you, at least, indicate which line of the code is causing the error?